# How to fetch data from database for each row of a dynamic table while iterating

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am having some challenges trying to implement this and will appreciate every help.
I have a simple html form for making orders. More fields can be generated dynamically for more orders. Each time a user selects a product a table is displayed previewing the orders so far with a column in each row for the cost of the product. Now, the cost for each product is in a table in my database where an ajax call is made to pull the values from with my fetch_cost.php file. Issue is I keep getting a blank table each time i introduce the cost column. Please find my html, php and jquery script:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="" id="order_form">
    <fieldset class="orders_det">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="prod_type">Type</label>
            <select name="prod_type[]" class="form-control prod">
                <option value="">-- Select Products --</option>
                <option value="prod1">Prod1</option>
                <option value="prod2">Prod2</option>
                <option value="prod3">Prod3</option>
            </select>
        </div>                      
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="quant" class="control-label col-md-2" >Quantity</label>
            <div class="form-control col-md-6">
              <input type="text" class="form-control quant" name="quant[]">
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="more_btn">Add More Orders + </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="more_orders">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="col-md-2 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control name" name="name">
        </div>
    </div>                      
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="order_submit" id="order_submit">Submit Order</button>
```

My Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('form button#more_btn').on("click", function(e) {//to generate dynamic fields
        e.preventDefault();
        var moreOrders = '';
              moreOrders += '<div class="new_order">';
              moreOrders += '<div class="form-group">';
              moreOrders += '<label for="prod_type">Type</label>';
              moreOrders += '<select name="prod_type[]" class="form-control prod">';
              moreOrders += '<option value="">-- Select Products --</option>';
              moreOrders += '<option value="prod1">Prod1</option>';
              moreOrders += '<option value="prod2">Prod2</option>';
              moreOrders += '<option value="prod3">Prod3</option>';
              moreOrders += '</select>';
              moreOrders += '</div> ';
              moreOrders += '<div class="form-group">';
              moreOrders += '<label for="quant" class="control-label col-md-2" >Quantity</label>';
              moreOrders += '<div class="form-control col-md-6">';
              moreOrders += '<input type="text" class="form-control quant" name="quant[]">';
              moreOrders += '</div>';
              moreOrders += '<div>';
              moreOrders += '</div><br />';
              $('.more_orders').append(moreOrders);
      });

      $("form").on("change", function(e) {//to generate a preview table
        var prod = $("form select[name='prod_type[]']");
        var quant = $("form input[name='quant[]']");
        var table = '';
              table += '<table>';
              table += '<thead>';
              table += '<tr>';
              table += '<th>Product</th>';
              table += '<th>Quantity</th>';
              table += '<th>Cost</th>';
              table += '</tr>';
              table += '</thead>';
              table += '<tbody>';
              table += '<tr>';
            prod.each(function(i) {
                $.post('fetch_cost.php', {'type':$(this).val()}, function(cost){
                  table += '<tr>';
                  table += '<td>' + $(this).val() + '</td>';
                  table += '<td>' + quant.eq(i).val() + '</td>';
                  table += '<td>' + cost + '</td>';
                  table += '</tr>';
                 });
                });
              table += '</tr>';
              table += '</tbody>';
              table += '</table>';
              $(".orders_preview").html(table);
            });
    });
```

And my fetch_cost.php page:

```
<?php
      require("conn.php");
      $type = $_POST['type'];
      $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT cost from product_cost WHERE product ='$type'");
            if ($sql){
                  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($sql)){
                        $cost = $row[0];
                        echo $cost;
                  }
            }
?>
```

N.B: For each product selected, the row should display the product, the quantity as selected and the cost of that product as fetched by fetch_cost.php.

Comment: Your SQL is vulnerable to injection attacks. Please learn how to use parameterised queries to protect your data from theft, deletion or corruption. http://bobby-tables.com/ contains an introduction to the topic and some examples including for PHP/mysqli. Otherwise your data is at risk from hackers and also your code is more likely to suffer logical errors such as datatype or syntax problems.

Comment: in the meantime, what debugging have you done? Have you verified that your "type" field is submitted to the server correctly (you can check your browser's network tab)? Have you run your query separately in MySQL Workbench to check it returns results? Have you checked that your ajax call returns successfully and contains data in the response (again check your network tab). It will help to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson.i will use parameterised queries surely. I'm only trying to sort out the logical structure of my code first. I have tried debugging and i get a 200(ok) showing my "type" field is submitted. i also console.log the "type" and the values were displayed ok.Please note that the prod.each is in fact type.each.I've corrected the typo

Comment: ok so what about the query, does it return any results?

Comment: Yes @ Adyson.It does.A test on phpmyadmin returned result.The issue seems to b in my iteration.I just couldn't figure out where exactly.

Comment: Actually I just noticed something else. Examine your final HTML after you run your code. I think you might find the table rows are missing, even though your query returned results, because $.post (as with all ajax) is asynchronous...therefore it will append the `</table>` to your `table` variable before it appends the rows. And then `$(".orders_preview").html(table);` will run as well before the row markup is created. You need to wait for all the ajax requests to complete before you finish your table markup and append it to the DOM. You can use jquery's `$.when` to help with that.

Comment: Either that, or simplify it by creating an ajax call which sends all the "type" variables as an array in one ajax call. Then it's trivial to wait for it to return before you populate your HTML.

Comment: I appreciate your assistance @ADyson.I will try these out and get back to u shortly.

Comment: Once again I so appreciate your assistance @ADyson. My code works very well now.Just a simple oversight..I had to take d closing table tag out of the loop and everything was fine. Thanks.